# Why does the offset voltage have this polarity?

Tags: analog, differential, differential-amplifier

Consider the following from Chapter 3.5.6 of Analysis and Design of Analog Integrated Circuits by Gray, Hurst, Meyer, and Lewis:

[image]

As I ask about [in a separate question,](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/691129/why-is-an-offset-voltage-and-an-offset-current-sufficient-to-represent-mismatche) the authors claim that for some \$V_{OS}\$ and \$I_{OS}\$ and matched amplifier, we can convert from Fig 3.62a to 3.62b. To the extent that I am taking that on faith given my linked question, I don't follow why the polarity of $\$V_{OS}\$ is as chosen. On the next page they write

> The input offset voltage \$V_{OS}\$ is equal to the value of \$V_{ID} = V_{I1} − V_{I2}\$ that must be applied to the input to drive the differential output voltage \$V_{OD} = V_{O1} − V_{O2}\$ to zero.

On the basis of this, I would expect the source in Fig 3.62b to have the *opposite* polarity. That is, since \$V_{OD} = 0\$ for a matched amplifier (as in Fig 3.62b) if and only if it's differential input is zero, we must then demand by KVL that \$V_{ID} + V_{OS} = 0\$, which is to say \$V_{ID} =- V_{OS}\$. But this appears opposite to what the authors conclude:

Where am I going wrong?

[image]

Comment: I think it might just be a matter of definitions, because in reality, for real op-amps the offsets can go either way depending on the design. As long as you are consistent. The consistency here being is that Vos is being treated as a source and that determines what you must define Ios as relative to Vos.

Answer (score 3):

The polarity as drawn does not really matter, it's just there as notation for calculations to keep track of the signs.

For any amplifier, the offset voltage required to bring output differential to zero could be any value within range of specified values, and the range can include positive and negative voltage.

So as drawn, the required offset could be positive or negative in sign.

So it does not matter if based on your chosen notation you need to add a positive offset or subtract a negative offset. It does not even matter if you put the offset on the negative input instead of the positive input, as long as your formula matches that notation.

In the end, regardless of the notation, the differential voltage required at the input terminals will be equal.

Comment: But given the definition used in the text, their polarity and the equation (3.207) seems to contradict each other, don't they?